# Add python project as a dependency of another

Tags: python, dependencies, project, directory-structure

I have a git repository with 4 folders, each of them is a python project. Since some of them want to be able to use functions/class that are in another of the projects but I don't know how to do it.

```
repository folder
  |> project 1
  |   |> class1.py
  |   |> class2.py
  |> project 2
  |   |> class10.py
  |   |> class20.py
  |> project 3
  |   |> class11.py
  |   |> class21.py
  |> project 4
  |   |> class110.py
  |   |> class210.py
```

For example, how I can add `project 1` as dependency in `project 4`?

EDIT: a new folder structure:

```
repository_folder
  |> project_1
  |   |> class1.py
  |   |> class2.py
  |> project_2
  |   |> class10.py
  |   |> class20.py
  |> project_3
  |   |> class11.py
  |   |> class21.py
  |> project_4
  |   |> class110.py
  |   |> class210.py
  |   |> folder_1
  |   |   |> class_3.py
  |   |> tests
  |   |   |> test_1.py
  |   |   |> test_2.py
```

Do I need a `__init__.py` file into `project_4/folder_1` folder if I need code from `project_1`? and into `project_4/tests` folder?

What about `__all__`?

Can I have a `__init__.py` and `from/import` example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `__init__.py` file in all your modules, it can be empty or containing a `__all__` structure.

Then I would suggest to remove the spaces in the names:

```
"project 1" -> "project_one"
"repository folder" -> "repository_folder"
```

The path structure will look like:

```
repository_folder
  |> project_one
  |   |> __init__.py
  |   |> class1.py
  |   |> class2.py
  |> project_two
  |   |> __init__.py
  |   |> class10.py
  |   |> class20.py
  |> project_three
  |   |> __init__.py
  |   |> class11.py
  |   |> class21.py
  |> project_four
  |   |> __init__.py
  |   |> class110.py
  |   |> class210.py
```

Then in your project_one simply import from the other projects as:

```
from repository_folder.project_one import class1
```

Or more likely:

```
from repository_folder.project_one.class1 import your_class_to import
```

In the import make sure you are importing what you want, you may want to import some class of the module, all the functions or the whole module.

Finally you need to ensure that your `path` when you run project4 contains the root of the project, otherwise it won't locate the modules. There are different ways of doing this, and some IDEs make it automatically (pyCharm), but if you are working from the terminal you can add it as a environment variable, or even do that from the code itself (but i don't recommend that).

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, my name folders are without space characteres, it was only a uncky example. I have edited my original question with a problem with unit tests and subolders. Can you help me?